# How to register an existing Jersey MessageBodyReader Provider as handling additional Content Types?

Tags: java, jersey

I have a REST webservice that handles JSON requests. I want to implement against the SCIM spec, to allow an Azure AD integration to provision users within my application.

I've written the method:

```
@POST
@Path("/scim/Users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
ScimUser createUser(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authHeader,
                    ScimUser user);
```

However, AAD is making requests with `Content-Type: application/scim+json`, so my application is returning a **415: Media Type Not Supported** error.

If I just swap over to

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/scim+json"})
```

My application routes the request to the correct method, but *still* throws a 415 error, this time because it can't find an appropriate message body reader.

I *have* a MessageBodyReader that can handle the incoming messages; "scim+json" is fully parsable as JSON. However, I can't modify the library code to add a new `@Consumes` annotation onto the existing class.

Is there a way to let Jersey know that this class can handle these messages?

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to create a new class:

```
@Provider
@Consumes(ScimService.SCIM_JSON_TYPE)
@Produces(ScimService.SCIM_JSON_TYPE)
public class ScimJsonProvider extends ExistingJsonProvider {
    public ScimJsonProvider() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and register *that*, but this feels kind of hacky, and I'd like to know if there's a better way.

**Edit:** this also doesn't seem to work; it seems like this ScimJsonProvider is sometimes being selected as the MessageBodyWriter for `application/json` events, and then later is throwing a 415 because that's not a type registered in its `@Produces` list. :(